# System.Exception: No such host is known

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I just started my UWP application tests on a Raspberry Pi 3 board. But the application started to throw exception: System.Exception: No such host is known when trying to reach the standard NTP server. This worked well in debug mode. Please advise me what should be the fix.

Comment: These tests are on the release version of my application. The debug version worked fine.

Comment: The host name is "pool.ntp.org".

Comment: I use: VS 2017 v 15.4.4, .NET Framework v4.7.02053, W8in IoT Core Insiders preview build 10.0.17035.1000. This problem happens only when I deploy my application from VS 2017 in Release mode and set it as a startup application from device Portal. Then I reset or reboot Win 10 IoT from the Dashboard.

Comment: Does the host name is 'pool.ntp.org' in your comment mean that your device(Raspberry Pi3)'s name is pool.ntp.org? Could you please describe your operation steps in detail.I have tested an application on 17035, i set the application as startup,even though in debug mode or release mode,when i restart my device,there is no any exception,the application works fine.Could you please provide primary code snippet of your application?

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT - http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/  pool.ntp.org is a large group of time servers.

Comment: As I explained, I gave the host name just as a reference. My application works fine in debug and release mode when ran from VS 2017 in a Raspberry Pi 3 board. Part of its initialization process is to synchronize its local time with the global UTC time. The problem occurred when I deployed my application to the same board and configured it to run as a standalone startup application. Here is the code which runs fine from VS 2017 and causes problems in the deployed application:                    await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("pool.ntp.org"), "123");

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the position of calling '*await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("pool.ntp.org"), "123");* '.When the application is initializing, the network calls should not be handled.According with [UWP Application lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle),please note that:

> If an app needs to request data from the **network** or needs to retrieve large amounts of data from disk, these activities should be completed **outside of launch**.

Network calls should be handled when the application is in **LeavingBackground**  state.LeavingBackground is the time to ensure the first frame of UI is ready. 
I have posted my test demo in GitHub([NTPDemo](https://github.com/v-liujxu/NTPDemo.git)).In this demo, if ***client.GetNetworkTimeAsync*** method is called in the constructor of MainPage, application will block at *socket.ConnectAsync*.In fact at this time, the application has not been in **Running** state.If the method is called in ***OnNavigatedTo***, it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Originally my application is a headless one. So I overlooked the Main page load completion requirement. Did you try to deploy your sample application to a Raspberry Pi 3 boards and run it on power-on? I applied the change you suggested and still got the NTP server exception in my application deployed version on the second Reset or Shutdown from the Dashboard and manual power-on. Still I wonder why when executed from VS 2017 in Debug or Release mode my application was able to correctly run the NTP code even without considering the Main page load completion.

Comment: My Raspberry Pi 3 board running my deployed as startup UWP application just reported that "the PC ran into a problem and need to restart..." without giving a reasonable explanation. After I restarted my application, it  again reported the "No such host is known" exception. After the fix you suggested, I used to restart it from Device Portal and it did not show this problem. Then I switched the board power off/on and the problem repeated. Do you have some suggestions? How can I get a reasonable trace of all these events in Win 10 IoT on Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: You can use [Event Tracing for Windows(ETW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/eventtracing) to trace the events. ETW provides trace event,and consume trace events of an application.Or you can also add some log tracing in your application.Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I do have a log but this didn't give the information I needed about the source and nature of the Win 10 IoT behavior.

Comment: When running my deployed application the "System.Exception: No such host is known.. " is still reported. It doesn't show in debug mode. Please let me know if you have a clue for this behavior.

Comment: Could you share more your source code?So that i can check the differences between mine and yours.I have not encounter this exception.

Comment: It seems that Win 10 IoT has been improved. The "System.Exception: No such host is known... " does not happen now in release mode. My code did not change.